# Is it possible to have routerLink and a click event on same anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular-ui-router

I have a bunch of `li` elements and when the user clicks them, it opens a more detailed view of those elements in a different component.

However, it requres TWO clicks to show the data I want to show.

When the user click **ONCE** the component opens up with the empty view template.

When the user clicks **AGAIN** it then shows the populated data.

Can I not just put this in one anchor tag that routes me to me detailed view *and* emits the click event in one?

Is there a preferred method or better way to do this?

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let favorite of sortedFavorites; let i= index">
    <a class= 'clickMe' (click)= "openContact($event, i)" routerLink= "/details">
    <div *ngIf= "favorite.isFavorite">
        <img class="smallImage" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='User Icon Small.png';"
             src={{favorite.smallImageURL}} />
        <h3><img src="Favorite — True.png">{{ favorite.name }}</h3>
        <br>
        <p>{{ favorite.companyName }}</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Some people are suggesting that I use reslove guards to fetch the data before it is populated, but I am only pulling this from a local JSON file and passing it between my components.

Comment: This is very common use case, but it isn't achieved the way we think of achieving it traditionally with JS. With Angular, this type of use case is solved with router guards. Here is a link the docs that discuss **your exact use case**: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard I can't provide this as an answer because you didn't specifically ask about the "preferred method" or something like that.

Comment: I'd love to hear any preferred methods that may be better! Original post updated...

Comment: The preferred method is to load the data using a resolve-guard. You can have multiple guards do all sorts of different things for each and every route. So if there is a bunch of pre-fetching of data or transformation or authorization, and on and on _prior_ to actually navigating to a route we use guards.  The link above shows you specifically how to use a guard to pre-fetch the data for a route. This example removes the need for your click handler you've placed on your controller and the controller method. That method moves to the guard. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure that I would need this? I'm only fetching a local JSON file and passing it between my components. I don't think this is a delay based issue because I'm not pulling it from any back end server. Are you sure I just don't have my click event or anything else set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use click event for both. navigate to details page via programmatically using the router

```
 this.router.navigate(['path']);
```

whatever process do in openContact() and then redirect on the details page.

add into constructor `private router: Router`

Comment: I was able to get this working by assigning `this.router.navigate(['path']);` To my openContact() method and adding the Router to the constructor. This Router functionality works, but it is still not populating my data to the component. But I will mark it correct because you technically answered my question.